# Unordered list show next and hide previous - JS fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('#loadMore').click(function () {
```

when `#loadMore` is clicked i want to show next 5 `<li>` and hide previous 5 `<li>` which is already showing there.

For Example when i click 1st time on load more

**One -(hidden)

Two -(hidden)

Three-(hidden)

Four-(hidden)

Five-(hidden)**

and

**six -(show)

seven -(show)

eight -(show)

nine -(show)

ten -(show)**

i tried to fix the code but there is little problem. once it hidden but then it show all element at once.

This is example of my JS code. and please prefer to fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=5;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
          $('#myList li').hide(500);
            x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
                $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show(500);
            $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
                $('#myList li').show(500);
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide(500);
        $('#loadMore').show();
         $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == 3){
            $('#showLess').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle Here : http://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/4460/

Comment: "please fix this asap"? you think this is a coding service*?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i am asking help

Comment: The problem is the way you ask, its not very kind

Comment: I am sorry @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/6FzSb/4465/). Hope this is what you want.

Have changed the code using slice function like below.

```
var pageSize = 5;
var currentPage = 1;
var total = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
total = $("#myList li").size();
$('#myList li:lt(' + pageSize + ')').show(500);

$('#loadMore').click(function() {
    if (total <= pageSize * (currentPage + 1)) {
        $("#loadMore").hide(500);
    }

    $("#myList li").hide(500);

    currentPage++;

    $("#myList li").slice(pageSize * (currentPage - 1), pageSize * currentPage).show(500);

    $("#showLess").show();
});
$('#showLess').click(function() {

    if (currentPage == 2) {
        $("#showLess").hide();
    }
    $("#myList li").hide(500);
    currentPage--;

    $("#myList li").slice(pageSize * (currentPage - 1), pageSize * currentPage).show(500);
    $("#loadMore").show();
});
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer Thank You so much for exact reply.

Comment: Welcome Gautam! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to happen here. Maybe you can update your question to clarify.

However I think the following will do what you want. I have removed the `hide` call in the `#showMore` event and the `show` call in the `#showLess` event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    var x=5;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show(500);
        $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<=0) ? 3 : x-5; /* Changed to <= so there are never 0 records */
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide(500);
        $('#loadMore').show();
        $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == 3){
            $('#showLess').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When i click on `load more` i want to show next 5 <li> and Hide previous 5 <li>